# Add a ListView with NavigationDrawer

Tags: android, listview, navigation-drawer

I am developing an application and I want to add a Navigation drawer and a ListView in the content_main.xml file.
When I add a ListView or Fragment in the content_main.xml, it throws exception.   The exception is `InflateException`.
Here is the description of what I want to do.

[image]

I know it is a very short description, but I did not find any way to describe it better.
If you can help me with this, please do help me.

Here is the logcat

```
12-12 11:17:26.923 29725-29725/com.antzion.salmanali.lockapp     E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
   Process: com.antzion.salmanali.lockapp, PID: 29725
   android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Binary XML     file line #17: Error inflating class android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuItemView
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
   at android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter$NormalViewHolder.<init>(NavigationMenuPresenter.java:288)
   at android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter$NavigationMenuAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(NavigationMenuPresenter.java:388)
   at android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter$NavigationMenuAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(NavigationMenuPresenter.java:338)
   at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.createViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:5836)
   at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5060)
   at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:4970)
   at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2029)
   at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1414)
   at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1377)
   at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:578)
   at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3315)
   at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3124)
   at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:3568)
   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16630)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
   at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:336)
   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:273)
   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16630)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
   at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onLayout(DrawerLayout.java:1221)
   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16630)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
   at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:336)
   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:273)
   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16630)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1743)
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1586)
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1495)
   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16630)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
   at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:336)
   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:273)
   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16630)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1743)
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1586)
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1495)
   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16630)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
   at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:336)
   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:273)
   at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onLayout(PhoneWindow.java:2678)
   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16630)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2171)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1931)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1107)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6013)
   at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:858)
   at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:670)
   at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:606)
at android.view.Ch
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: It would be useful if you could show the full logcat. "InflateException" isn't the error. Read all the lines that say "Caused by"

Comment: @cricket_007 i have found that when i remove the id from the listView it works perfectly fine but when i write the line                                                              android:id="@+id/listView"              it gives exception

Comment: Have you tried `android:id="@android:id/list"`?

Comment: @cricket_007 that worked. What was the error and why did this work while the other didn't?

Comment: and also thank you.

Comment: Honestly, was a complete guess. If you are using a `ListActivity`, that is required. You can read that in the documentation - https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html ... *your own view MUST contain a ListView object with the id `@android:id/list`*

Comment: Also, by the way, the NavigationView typically does not go within the `content_main.xml` because that is the layout behind the NavigationView.

Comment: @cricket_007 now how do i get the reference to listView in my java file? I am not using ListActivity. I am using AppcompatActivity.

Comment: Like normal, just a different ID. `findViewById(android.R.id.list)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to move the comments to an answer.

Use `android:id="@android:id/list"`, which is the built-in system's list ID for most list-related views.

You can get a reference to that like normal, but with a different ID than `R.id`.

```
listView = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
```

Comment: Okay, thank you. That solved my problem. Thanks a lot.